# how in nginx to redirect location to any host received urls?

Tags: nginx

I need to get the host address from the request and redirect to another host with the rewritten address, but in all possible ways I failed

Here's an example (one of the attempts):

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://...;
  ...
}

location /service/(.*)$/ {
  rewrite /service/$1/(.*)$ /$2 break;
  proxy_pass http://$1.localhost:8080/;
  ...
}
```

Works only if hardcoded:

```
location /service/hostaname/ {
   rewrite /service/hostaname/(.*)$ /$1 break;
   proxy_pass http://hostaname.localhost:8080/;
   ...
}
```

But this is not a suitable solution for me

Help meeeeeee, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `location` syntax is invalid, as it is missing the *regular expression* operator. The `rewrite` statement contains an invalid regular expression.

You do not need the `rewrite` statement as you can extract the parts of the URI from the `location` statement.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/service/([^/]+)/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://$1.localhost:8080/$2;
}
```

You may need to define a `resolver` statement as the `proxy_pass` contains variables. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) for details.

Comment: Hey!
Thanks for the answer - you are really right, now me need a resolver, but I can't add it - it doesn't work with localhost...
how to add [dynamic] - $1.localhost resolver?

do i need to do something with my local dns?